# forward winapi events to another window

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

What i have now: my app in C# is half-transparent, and does not catch winapi events - every click, drag etc is catch by underlaying window, which is separate app (like webbrower). I use this to overlay information on top of what browser shows.  This is my code for this:

```
int exstyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
exstyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle);

IntPtr hwndf = this.Handle;
IntPtr hwndParent = GetDesktopWindow();
SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);
```

But now, i would like to send all events to both my app window (which is half-transparent on top) and web browser (under my app). So for example if i click, the click works in both windows as if they were on top. I imagine that only way to do that is to catch all events and then forward them to lower window, but is there any way to do that? 
I use winforms as window lib.

---

What i do now is not that important, because i want to normally consume events, then forward them to underlaying window. So this is something completly different from what i'm doing now with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT. The point of this is to drag content in both windows simultaneously. If there is any better way of doing it, i would be glad to hear it.

---

As least what i need is to transfer drag events to both windows, and all other events to underlaying window (not under my control). So, perhaps it will be easier to stay with my window as WS_EX_TRANSPARENT (makes events pass-thru to underlaying window) and simply install global hook to receive drag events? What do you think?

BTW i don't have experience with Winapi, so solution might be obvious.

Comment: I don't understand how you're not getting events... are you creating an actual window (you should)? Or just drawing directly to the screen (you shouldn't!)?

Comment: @tenfour By setting the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` style.

Comment: @tenfour yes, i use window created by .net winform, and drawing is handled by winform, so it's created window. I only setup a style WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and set window parent as desktop, which makes event pass to underlaying window, like here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12877/Transparent-Click-Through-Forms
and yes, it does make messages not come into window, as long as window is child of desktop directly.

Comment: @tenfour if i remove WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, window on top would catch all the events. How then I'm supposed to forward them to underlaying window?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture Windows events sent your own form by overloading WndProc on the form, or alternatively by calling `user32!GetMessage`

You can send messages to other Windows forms via the `user32!PostMessage` or `user32!SendMessage` apis ([read PostMessage function on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You could try forwarding the event after the underlying form has handled it. Something like

```
 protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs drgevent)
 {
     base.OnDragOver(drgevent);
     MyControl.ForwardDragEvent(drgevent);
 }
```

In MyControl:

```
public void ForwardDragEvent(DragEventArgs drgevent)
{
     base.OnDragOver(drgevent);
     //Or call your own method to handle the event
}
```

I have used this to forward scroll-events, in my case however, only one of the controls handled the event..